# asp-classic Request.Cookies brings this value "ϑ" for 1 cookie instead of "ÅÙÏ‘‹„‰Š„‹"

Tags: cookies, asp-classic

This is happening in one cookie with keys in one key only.
The value should be "ÅÙÏ‘‹„‰Š„‹".

Comment: oh boy, you might want to make this a little clearer with some more details

Comment: and, perhaps a different font, or unicode or something?

Comment: We see garbage for the value you quoted above.  If you see something different, you have to tell us what encoding you expect this to be in.

Comment: It is like garbage...it is a html encoded text. In the cookie actually I had this %C5%D9%CF%91%89%8D%8E%88%8D%8B

Comment: While debugging asp, in the VS2008 Watcher Request.cookies(myCookieName)  [RawView] Item I see the correct value. but then I try to reach the value using Request.Cookies(myCookieName)("myKey") I get the “ϑ”.

Comment: Corrupt cookies?  In that same Watcher Count for [RawView] value it shows "&H18"

Comment: Sorry "&H18" was the hexa value. It´s ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final Solution:
Save As different file with "correct" encoding
Changed encoding

- From "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) -Codepage 65001"
- To "Western European (Windows) - Codepage 1252"

Answer (score 2):

> The value should be "ÅÙÏ‘‹„‰Š„‹".

Erm, really? That looks like the corrupted, wrong-character set version to me! :-) Either way, “ϑ” is what you get when you save that string in Windows Western European encoding (cp1252) and then read it back in as UTF-8, removing all the ‘invalid character’ codes that result because it's not a valid UTF-8 string. So you've got a classic reading-and-writing-using-different-encodings problem.

As a general rule you can't get away with putting non-ASCII characters in a cookie (name or value) directly. You'll need an application-level encoding mechanism of some sort; one of the most popular ways is to URL-encode the UTF-8 representation of the characters you want, similarly to how JavaScript's encodeURIComponent does it.

(Unfortunately ASP classic has very poor support for handling Unicode.)

Answer (score 0):

We're using encoding on our cookies and some of the resulting characters can cause problems. So what we did is take the cookie string and encode it in HEX. - Problems Solved.